# What would be implications of Ethereum's merge for MEV searchers?

Tags: proof-of-stake, the-merge, mev, mev-searcher, mev-boost

Within a few days, Ethereum will eventually be transmitted from PoW to PoS. The question is will MEV searchers (who use MEV relay API) need to do any update on their code? (i.e. change relay API address).
Will libraries such as [ethers-provider-bundle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@flashbots/ethers-provider-bundle) be working post-merge or they also need to be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the successful completion of the ⟠ Ethereum ⟠ merge ⛙, it has now become clear that as a searcher, you can rely on the good old Flashbots relay! and you do not require to take any further action or change in your code which of course is absolutely logical, regarding the architecture of the new [MEV-boost](https://github.com/flashbots/mev-boost) and BPS models.

**Update:**
For the sake of Ethereum neutrality, please use independent relays which are **NOT** OFAC compliant. `Manifold` and `Relayooor` are two of them.

[image: MEV-Boost]

**Update2:** For more details, see [this post](https://writings.flashbots.net/searching-post-merge) by flashbots.